# Magento filter the search results order by quantity

Tags: magento

Thanks in advance,

For filter the search result in magento in which file i have to make the changes please help.

i want to filter the result order by qunatity

Thanks..

Comment: i have tried in search.php but not sure where to change..

Answer (score -2):

In magento filtering based on attributes. That is if there are 10 products and  have the color blue. After searching i can view the filter like these blue(10). Could you please explain the question once more?

Comment: is this an answer or question??

Comment: I told about magento filter feature